# How to get direct video link from odnoklassniki (ok.ru)

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get video direct video link from ok.ru, so i created this php script to fetch the page data and it returns json file

```
<?php
$id ="947875089023";
$html = file_get_contents("https://ok.ru/videoembed/".$id);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(2);
$json = $node->getAttribute("data-options");
echo $json;
?>
```

After getting json file i used JavaScript to get the all video urls

```
const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(
   {"playerId":"VideoPopup_player_947875089023","width":"491","height":"275","notifyEnabled":true,"url":"https://st.mycdn.me/static/MegaPlayer/10-10-15/vp.swf","url11":"https://st.mycdn.me/static/MegaPlayer/10-10-15/vp11.swf","html5url":"//st.mycdn.me/static/MegaPlayer/10-11-60/okHtml5Player.min","minFlashVersionNewPlayer":"11.2","wmode":"opaque","asa":true,"provider":"UPLOADED_ODKL","flashvars":{"relatedAlways":"1","metadata":"{\"provider\":\"UPLOADED_ODKL\",\"service\":\"ok\",\"owner\":false,\"voted\":false,\"likeCount\":0,\"subscribed\":false,\"isWatchLater\":false,\"slot\":690,\"siteZone\":-1,\"showAd\":true,\"fromTime\":0,\"author\":{\"id\":\"571310739583\",\"name\":\"riki altwan\",\"profile\":\"/profile/571310739583\"},\"movie\":{\"id\":\"947875089023\",\"movieId\":\"947875089023\",\"likeId\":\"947875089023\",\"contentId\":\"426740025983\",\"poster\":\"https://i.mycdn.me/videoPreview?id=426740025983\\u0026type=37\\u0026idx=0\\u0026tkn=pAfyf6Av9sm4uotfYjxQFcRyGbE\\u0026fn=external_8\",\"duration\":\"1449\",\"title\":\"[WEHOH.COM]Ca_Tsu_-Ep30-to\",\"url\":\"https://ok.ru/video/947875089023\",\"link\":\"/video/947875089023\",\"collageInfo\":{\"imageType\":\"COLLAGE\",\"url\":\"https://i.mycdn.me/videoPreview?id=426740025983\\u0026type=36\\u0026idx=0\\u0026tkn=WzWDCxAWX5dKTWRFiQBcXzhZlx8\",\"frequency\":10,\"height\":44,\"width\":80,\"count\":145,\"tileWidth\":0,\"tileHeight\":0},\"status\":\"OK\",\"statusText\":\"OK\",\"isLive\":false,\"notPublished\":false},\"admanMetadata\":{},\"partnerId\":-1,\"ownerUserId\":\"571310739583\",\"ownerMovieId\":\"947875089023\",\"alwaysShowRec\":false,\"videos\":[{\"name\":\"mobile\",\"url\":\"https://vd335.mycdn.me/?expires=1630432672237\\u0026srcIp=95.217.203.187\\u0026srcAg=UNKNOWN\\u0026ms=185.226.53.44\\u0026type=4\\u0026sig=wLDgZ2Ncspg\\u0026ct=0\\u0026urls=185.226.52.60\\u0026clientType=0\\u0026id=426740025983\",\"seekSchema\":3,\"disallowed\":false},{\"name\":\"lowest\",\"url\":\"https://vd335.mycdn.me/?expires=1630432672237\\u0026srcIp=95.217.203.187\\u0026srcAg=UNKNOWN\\u0026ms=185.226.53.44\\u0026type=0\\u0026sig=0DoDfFzi6XM\\u0026ct=0\\u0026urls=185.226.52.60\\u0026clientType=0\\u0026id=426740025983\",\"seekSchema\":3,\"disallowed\":false},{\"name\":\"low\",\"url\":\"https://vd335.mycdn.me/?expires=1630432672237\\u0026srcIp=95.217.203.187\\u0026srcAg=UNKNOWN\\u0026ms=185.226.53.44\\u0026type=1\\u0026sig=h4uYrTtMkQ8\\u0026ct=0\\u0026urls=185.226.52.60\\u0026clientType=0\\u0026id=426740025983\",\"seekSchema\":3,\"disallowed\":false},{\"name\":\"sd\",\"url\":\"https://vd335.mycdn.me/?expires=1630432672237\\u0026srcIp=95.217.203.187\\u0026srcAg=UNKNOWN\\u0026ms=185.226.53.44\\u0026type=2\\u0026sig=whiWdFAPXwU\\u0026ct=0\\u0026urls=185.226.52.60\\u0026clientType=0\\u0026id=426740025983\",\"seekSchema\":3,\"disallowed\":false},{\"name\":\"hd\",\"url\":\"https://vd335.mycdn.me/?expires=1630432672237\\u0026srcIp=95.217.203.187\\u0026srcAg=UNKNOWN\\u0026ms=185.226.53.44\\u0026type=3\\u0026sig=bGmvbFQz7NA\\u0026ct=0\\u0026urls=185.226.52.60\\u0026clientType=0\\u0026id=426740025983\",\"seekSchema\":3,\"disallowed\":false}],\"metadataEmbedded\":\"\\u003C?xml version=\\\"1.0\\\" encoding=\\\"UTF-8\\\"?\\u003E\\u003CMPD xmlns:xsi=\\\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\\\" xmlns=\\\"urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011\\\" xsi:schemaLocation=\\\"urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011\\\" type=\\\"static\\\" mediaPresentationDuration=\\\"PT1449.2S\\\" minBufferTime=\\\"PT0.5S\\\" profiles=\\\"urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-on-demand:2011\\\"\\u003E\\u003CPeriod id=\\\"0\\\" start=\\\"PT0S\\\" duration=\\\"PT1449.2S\\\"\\u003E\\u003CAdaptationSet id=\\\"0\\\" segmentAlignment=\\\"true\\\" subsegmentAlignment=\\\"true\\\" subsegmentStartsWithSAP=\\\"1\\\"\\u003E\\u003CRepresentation id=\\\"0\\\" bandwidth=\\\"104768\\\" width=\\\"256\\\" height=\\\"144\\\" quality=\\\"mobile\\\" frameRate=\\\"24\\\" codecs=\\\"avc1.64000C,mp4a.40.2\\\" audioSamplingRate=\\\"44100\\\" mimeType=\\\"video/mp4\\\" startWithSAP=\\\"1\\\"\\u003E\\u003CBaseURL\\u003Ehttps://vd335.mycdn.me/?expires=1630432672237\\u0026amp;srcIp=95.217.203.187\\u0026amp;srcAg=UNKNOWN\\u0026amp;ms=185.226.53.44\\u0026amp;type=4\\u0026amp;sig=wLDgZ2Ncspg\\u0026amp;ct=4\\u0026amp;urls=185.226.52.60\\u0026amp;clientType=0\\u0026amp;id=426740025983\\u003C/BaseURL\\u003E\\u003CSegmentBase indexRange=\\\"1369-2564\\\"\\u003E\\u003CInitialization range=\\\"0-1368\\\"/\\u003E\\u003C/SegmentBase\\u003E\\u003C/Representation\\u003E\\u003CRepresentation id=\\\"1\\\" bandwidth=\\\"297152\\\" width=\\\"426\\\" height=\\\"240\\\" quality=\\\"lowest\\\" frameRate=\\\"24\\\" codecs=\\\"avc1.640015,mp4a.40.2\\\" audioSamplingRate=\\\"44100\\\" mimeType=\\\"video/mp4\\\" startWithSAP=\\\"1\\\"\\u003E\\u003CBaseURL\\u003Ehttps://vd335.mycdn.me/?expires=1630432672237\\u0026amp;srcIp=95.217.203.187\\u0026amp;srcAg=UNKNOWN\\u0026amp;ms=185.226.53.44\\u0026amp;type=0\\u0026amp;sig=0DoDfFzi6XM\\u0026amp;ct=4\\u0026amp;urls=185.226.52.60\\u0026amp;clientType=0\\u0026amp;id=426740025983\\u003C/BaseURL\\u003E\\u003CSegmentBase indexRange=\\\"1375-2570\\\"\\u003E\\u003CInitialization range=\\\"0-1374\\\"/\\u003E\\u003C/SegmentBase\\u003E\\u003C/Representation\\u003E\\u003CRepresentation id=\\\"2\\\" bandwidth=\\\"623897\\\" width=\\\"640\\\" height=\\\"360\\\" quality=\\\"low\\\" frameRate=\\\"24\\\" codecs=\\\"avc1.64001E,mp4a.40.2\\\" audioSamplingRate=\\\"44100\\\" mimeType=\\\"video/mp4\\\" startWithSAP=\\\"1\\\"\\u003E\\u003CBaseURL\\u003Ehttps://vd335.mycdn.me/?expires=1630432672237\\u0026amp;srcIp=95.217.203.187\\u0026amp;srcAg=UNKNOWN\\u0026amp;ms=185.226.53.44\\u0026amp;type=1\\u0026amp;sig=h4uYrTtMkQ8\\u0026amp;ct=4\\u0026amp;urls=185.226.52.60\\u0026amp;clientType=0\\u0026amp;id=426740025983\\u003C/BaseURL\\u003E\\u003CSegmentBase indexRange=\\\"1372-2567\\\"\\u003E\\u003CInitialization range=\\\"0-1371\\\"/\\u003E\\u003C/SegmentBase\\u003E\\u003C/Representation\\u003E\\u003CRepresentation id=\\\"3\\\" bandwidth=\\\"1088858\\\" width=\\\"852\\\" height=\\\"480\\\" quality=\\\"sd\\\" frameRate=\\\"24\\\" codecs=\\\"avc1.64001E,mp4a.40.2\\\" audioSamplingRate=\\\"44100\\\" mimeType=\\\"video/mp4\\\" startWithSAP=\\\"1\\\"\\u003E\\u003CBaseURL\\u003Ehttps://vd335.mycdn.me/?expires=1630432672237\\u0026amp;srcIp=95.217.203.187\\u0026amp;srcAg=UNKNOWN\\u0026amp;ms=185.226.53.44\\u0026amp;type=2\\u0026amp;sig=whiWdFAPXwU\\u0026amp;ct=4\\u0026amp;urls=185.226.52.60\\u0026amp;clientType=0\\u0026amp;id=426740025983\\u003C/BaseURL\\u003E\\u003CSegmentBase indexRange=\\\"1376-2571\\\"\\u003E\\u003CInitialization range=\\\"0-1375\\\"/\\u003E\\u003C/SegmentBase\\u003E\\u003C/Representation\\u003E\\u003CRepresentation id=\\\"4\\\" bandwidth=\\\"1982516\\\" width=\\\"1280\\\" height=\\\"720\\\" quality=\\\"hd\\\" frameRate=\\\"24\\\" codecs=\\\"avc1.64001F,mp4a.40.2\\\" audioSamplingRate=\\\"44100\\\" mimeType=\\\"video/mp4\\\" startWithSAP=\\\"1\\\"\\u003E\\u003CBaseURL\\u003Ehttps://vd335.mycdn.me/?expires=1630432672237\\u0026amp;srcIp=95.217.203.187\\u0026amp;srcAg=UNKNOWN\\u0026amp;ms=185.226.53.44\\u0026amp;type=3\\u0026amp;sig=bGmvbFQz7NA\\u0026amp;ct=4\\u0026amp;urls=185.226.52.60\\u0026amp;clientType=0\\u0026amp;id=426740025983\\u003C/BaseURL\\u003E\\u003CSegmentBase indexRange=\\\"1372-2567\\\"\\u003E\\u003CInitialization range=\\\"0-1371\\\"/\\u003E\\u003C/SegmentBase\\u003E\\u003C/Representation\\u003E\\u003C/AdaptationSet\\u003E\\u003C/Period\\u003E\\u003C/MPD\\u003E\",\"metadataUrl\":\"https://vd335.mycdn.me/?expires=1630432672237\\u0026srcIp=95.217.203.187\\u0026srcAg=UNKNOWN\\u0026ms=185.226.53.44\\u0026type=1\\u0026sig=h4uYrTtMkQ8\\u0026ct=6\\u0026urls=185.226.52.60\\u0026clientType=0\\u0026id=426740025983\",\"hlsManifestUrl\":\"https://vd335.mycdn.me/video.m3u8?cmd=videoPlayerCdn\\u0026expires=1630432672237\\u0026srcIp=95.217.203.187\\u0026srcAg=UNKNOWN\\u0026ms=185.226.53.44\\u0026type=4\\u0026sig=wLDgZ2Ncspg\\u0026ct=8\\u0026urls=185.226.52.60\\u0026clientType=0\\u0026id=426740025983\",\"failoverHosts\":[\"vd339.mycdn.me\"],\"autoplay\":{\"autoplayEnabled\":true,\"timeFromEnabled\":true,\"noRec\":false,\"fullScreenExit\":false,\"vitrinaSection\":\"recommended_movie\"},\"p2pInfo\":{\"isPeerEnabled\":false,\"ubsc\":0,\"pbsc\":0,\"mptpc\":0,\"pctmt\":0,\"pbesc\":0,\"prrt\":0,\"srt\":0,\"swrt\":0,\"dctt\":0},\"stunServers\":[{\"urls\":[\"stun:videostun.mycdn.me:80\"]}]}","saveLastPlayingTimeFrom":"30","castId":"559D7832","noDownload":"1","locale":"ru","noChatLikes":"1","noChannel":"1","webmSec":"20","enabledLocalStorage":"1","minCacheTime":"120","maxCachePartOfDurationMQ":"30","checkMQ":"1","noTrailer":"1","recSlot":"7178","noLikeButton":"1","maxCachePartOfDuration":"10","isAnonym":"1","jidx":"1","hideWatermark":"0","isEmbed":"1","noOkliveBanner":"1","minCacheTimeMQ":"20","ldChunk":"2000","showChat":"1","ldBuffer":"6000","feedAdLogic":"15,3,3,14400","siteId":"504","location":"AnonymVideoEmbed/anonymVideoEmbed/anonym","hideExpand":"1","adLogic":"15,0,3,14400","checkAutoplayBrowsers":"safari,chrome,opera,yandex,firefox"},"liveRertyTimeout":5000,"poster":"https://i.mycdn.me/videoPreview?id=426740025983\u0026type=37\u0026idx=0\u0026tkn=pAfyf6Av9sm4uotfYjxQFcRyGbE\u0026fn=external_8","isExternalPlayer":false,"isIframePlayer":false,"isHtml5Player":true,"timestamp":"1630346272240","stubEnabled":false,"verifyInline":false,"webrtcBrokenH264":false}
)).flashvars.metadata;
const video = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(obj))).videos; 
for (let i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
   url = video[i].url;
   name = video[i].name;
   if(name == "mobile"){
     var a = url;
}
document.write(a);
```

But now the problem is that i can't play those videos. Because the video links use same headers confirmation. As the link was fetched in server side, so it can't be play client side.

***Is there any other way to get direct video link from ok.ru? Or how can i sent client side fetch request to get the video link working in client side?***

Comment: Most likely, the site uses headers to make sure requests are coming from them. You could look at the headers and use them for the video request.

Comment: I tried it my self and it's working. You just have to use the same headers. If you need help, just ask.

Comment: Yes, I need help about it. How can I use headers for the video request? Can you give me an example? Or the full working code?

Comment: You need to make sure the user agent is a browser. Or else the request fails.

Answer (score 0):

The code should look something like this. A bit messy, because I'm not used to vanilla JS.

If you've got any questions, then just ask.

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const url = "https://ok.ru/videoembed/947875089023";
const userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0";

function getData(link) {
  return axios.get(link).then(res => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
      const dataOptions = $("[data-module=OKVideo]").attr("dataset").options;
      return new Promise.resolve(dataOptions);
    })
    .catch(err => new Promise.reject(err));
}

function extractUsefulData({
  url,
  expires,
  srcIp,
  srcAg,
  ms,
  type,
  sig,
  ct,
  urls,
  clientType,
  id
}) {
  return {
    url,
    expires,
    srcIp,
    srcAg,
    ms,
    type,
    sig,
    ct,
    urls,
    clientType,
    id
  }
}

function makeVideoLink(options) {
  const host = options.url;
  del options.url;
  const videoLink = url + Object.keys(options)
    .map(key => `${key}=${options[key]}`)
    .join('&');

  return videoLink;
}

function videoRequest(videoLink) {
  axios.get(videoLink, {
      headers: {
        "user-agent": userAgent;
      }
    })
    .then(res => new Promise.resolve(res.data))
    .catch(err => new Promise.reject(err));
}

getData(url)
  .then(data => extractUsefulData(data))
  .then(data => makeVideoLink(data))
  .then(link => videoRequest(link))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```